# C insertion sort stuck in while loop

Tags: c, loops, sorting, while-loop, insertion

I'm writing a simple program to sort a small array but when I run my code for insertion sort the program just runs forever.

It's probably a problem with the while loop.  I ran through the program on paper and looked over some other people's code but I can't figure out why it's not working.

```
void mySort(int d[], unsigned int n){   
        int i, j, k;
        for (j = 1;j < n;i++){
        k = d[j];
        i = j-1;

        while (d[i] > k && i >=0){
            d[i+1] = d[i];
            d[i] = k;
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger? Doesn't look like the insertion sort by the way...

Comment: Your for loop seems strange         for (j = 1;j < n;i++){

Answer (score 0):

```
for (j = 1;j < n;i++){
```

You compare value `j`, but you increment value `i`.

If you ***Use a Debugger***, you would immediately notice that the value `j` does not get updated, and you'd find your problem immediately!!

Always ***Use a Debugger***

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your for loop.

```
for (j = 1;j < n;i++){
```

So your terminating conditions of the for loop are that j >= n, except you never change j or n after this statement.

Try

```
for (j = 1;j < n;j++){
```